# Parametrisation of $\mathbb{S}^n$ and smooth atlas.

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, spheres

Two questions regarding the $n$-sphere:

1. construct a parametrization
2. what is the minimum number of charts needs for a smooth manifold of $\mathbb{S}^n$

---

With regards to the first question:

$$\varphi \in (0,2\pi)\quad \theta_n = (0,\pi)$$
$$\mathbb{S}^1(\theta,\varphi) = (\cos \varphi, \sin \varphi)$$
$$\mathbb{S^n}(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n,\varphi) = (\sin\theta_n)\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times (\cos\theta_n)$$
by which I mean the coordinates of the parametrization are:
$$
\mathbb{S^n}_i = (\sin\theta_n)\mathbb{S^{n-1}}_i
\quad i\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}
$$$$
\mathbb{S^n}_n = \cos\theta_n
$$
**Is there a way to write the parametrization without the use of recursion?**

With regards to the second question:

We need a minimum of $2$ charts to parametrize the circle into a smooth manifold.

We need a minimum of $4$ charts to parametrize the sphere into a smooth manifold.

So we need $2^n$ charts to parametrize $\mathbb{S}^n$, because for each incremental increase of the dimension we require two more charts to keep the
charts injective. **Is this reasoning correct?**

EDIT: with regards to the second question, I found out that you can have a generalised stereographic projection in such a way that only two charts are required to construct a smooth manifold:

$$\mathcal{A}=\{ (\mathbb{R}^n, x_N), (\mathbb{R}^n, x_N)   \}$$
where $x_N$ is the projection from the generalized North Pole and $x_S$ is 
respectively the projection from the South Pole.

Comment: The minimum number is two. You cant have just parametrization since it will leads to contradiction. The other standard chart is the projection of each hemisphere with $x^i>0$ (and $x^i<0$) to open ball $B^n$